# C++ Invalid read size 4 valgrind

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am getting a "invalid read size 4" error for some reason I can't figure out. I searched online for an answer and it didn't really help with my code. To summarize what my code does, it's a Stock Paper Trading Simulator. The user will be shown options and then they can choose what they would like to do. Right now I am having problems with "Sell a stock". Here's what it looks like.

```
Stock* newStock = new Stock(); 
view->getStockData(newStock);

Stock* s = stocks->findElement(newStock);

if(s->getAOS()-newStock->getAOS() > 0) { // There is still some shares remaining
    // Haven't done this yet        

} else if (s->getAOS()-newStock->getAOS() == 0) { // There is no shares remaining
        double result = s->calculate(newStock->getPrice(), s->getPrice(), s->getAOS());
        view->printResults(result, 0);

        stocks->remove(newStock);

} else { // Resulted with a negative value
    // Haven't done this yet    
}
```

view->getStockData(newStock); looks like this:

```
void UImanager::getStockData(Stock* stock) {
    // Initializing all the stock data
    string    str = "";
    string    symbol, companyName;
    double    price;
    int       amountOfShares;

    cout << endl << "Enter the stock's symbol (e.g. AAPL):  ";
    getline(cin, symbol);

    cout << endl << "Enter the companies name:   ";
    getline(cin, companyName);

    cout << endl << "Enter the price of the stock:   ";
    getline(cin, str);
    stringstream ss(str);
    ss >> price;
    str = "";

    cout << endl << "Enter the amount of shares:    ";
    getline(cin, str);
    stringstream ss1(str);
    ss1 >> amountOfShares;
    str = "";

    Stock* tmpStock = new Stock(symbol, companyName, price, amountOfShares); 
    *stock = *tmpStock;
    delete tmpStock;
}
```

The stock class looks like this:

```
Stock::Stock(string s, string c, double p, int aOS) {
    symbol = s;
    companyName = c;
    price = p;
    amountOfShares = aOS;
    fee = 10;
}

string Stock::getSymbol()      { return symbol; }
string Stock::getCompanyName() { return companyName; }
double Stock::getPrice()       { return price; }
int    Stock::getAOS()         { return amountOfShares; }
int    Stock::getFee()         { return fee; }

bool Stock::operator==(Stock& s) {
    if (this->getSymbol() == s.getSymbol()) {
        return true;
    }   

    return false;
}

// More below this, but that code doesn't matter for this problem
```

And I'm storing the stocks in a templated Dlist that I made. And this is findElement(T*):

```
template <class T>
T* Dlist<T>::findElement(T* item) {
    Node<T>* currNode = head;

    while (currNode != 0) { // iterate through the Dlist
        if (currNode->data == item) { // uses the operator overloaded == from Stock
            return currNode->data;
        }

        currNode = currNode->next;
    }

    // gets to this point if nothing was found
    return 0;
}
```

This is what valgrind says:

```
==2459== Invalid read of size 4
==2459==    at 0x804A4EC: Stock::getAOS() (in /home/student/Desktop/Stock Paper Trading/spt)
==2459==    by 0x8049356: SPTcontrol::launch() (in /home/student/Desktop/Stock Paper Trading/spt)
==2459==    by 0x8048F8D: main (in /home/student/Desktop/Stock Paper Trading/spt)
==2459==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2459== 
==2459== 
==2459== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2459==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==2459==    at 0x804A4EC: Stock::getAOS() (in /home/student/Desktop/Stock Paper Trading/spt)
==2459==    by 0x8049356: SPTcontrol::launch() (in /home/student/Desktop/Stock Paper Trading/spt)
==2459==    by 0x8048F8D: main (in /home/student/Desktop/Stock Paper Trading/spt)
```

So I understand that it's telling me that there is something wrong with accessing information from my stock class after finding it in the Dlist, but I really don't understand why or how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I notice you aren't checking if `Stock* s = stocks->findElement(newStock)` returns null

Comment: Yeah I put a check in to see if s is null and I found out it is. Now I'm tracking the problem, and it seems like the problem is coming for my operator overloaded == because I put cout's for item->getSymbol() and currNode->data->getSymbol() and they both were "AAPL" (What I put for testing) but it seems like currNode->data == item returns false for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as if `s` is a null pointer because `Dlist::findElement` is returning a null pointer.

The big clue is the address valgrind is complaining about. Do you see it says "Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or recently free'd"? It's extremely unusual (read: pretty much completely unheard-of) for genuine addresses to be so close to zero; what this almost always means is that your code encountered a null pointer, which happens to be represented by an address of zero on most systems, and then did some arithmetic on it (e.g., if a `Stock` is at address 0 then where is its `amountOfShares`? At address 16 = 0x10, perhaps).

You can check this by adding some code that explicitly checks for null pointers, or by running your code inside a debugger and stepping through it.

If my conjecture is right (or if it's wrong but some similar conjecture is right) would be why you're getting a null pointer from `Dlist::findElement`. But I'll let you work that one out for yourself.

Comment: Oh okay, now I know where to start to fix it. Thank you

Comment: The problem seems to be my operator overloaded function but I don't understand why? In findElement I changed if(currNode->data == item) to if(currNode->data->getSymbol() == item->getSymbol()) (This obviously defeats the purpose of the templated dlist) just to test it and it did work? It seems like it doesn't even call the operator overloaded == cause I put cout statements in it and they never got printed to the console? Do you have any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: We don't have the definition of the `Node` class, but if you can say things like `currNode->data->getSymbol()` then I take it `Node<T>::data` is of type `T *` rather than `T`. In that case, when you try to compare two of those you'll get a pointer comparison. Your `operator==` is for comparing two `Stock`s, and won't get called when two `Stock*`s are compared.

Comment: That did it! I changed the if(currNode->data == item) to if(*(currNode->data) == *item) and it works perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to accept my answer, which will get us both some extra reputation points.

Comment: Sorry this was my first time posting a question on stackoverflow haha I didn't even know that feature existed, I did it now though

Comment: No problem. (If someone answers your question to their satisfaction, it's a good idea to accept their answer because 1. it will give you a bit of extra rep, 2. it will reward them for doing something useful, 3. if you don't do it then others can see and may be less inclined to bother answering your questions, and 4. it provides useful information to other people reading the question and answers later.)